# Is there a way to protect a disk from being formatted by parted?

Tags: partition, disk, parted

It happens that here in my company we have our mail servers and everytime we need to upgrade disk space, we add a new disk in our VM and add it to the LVM, format it with parted and add the partition to the vg.

I would like to know if there is a way to protect one of those disks (for example, /dev/sdf) from being partitioned in parted. For example, if someone runs `parted /dev/sdf` a warning would show up or something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to modify `parted` and add such functionality, far as I can tell. And it wouldn't protect you from someone using anything else but `parted`. So, I guess that's a "no".

Also, this sounds like a very particular way of dealing with extensible storage for VMs. I'd argue you'd usually want the Volume Manager to run on the host side, and extend the size of the volume offered to the VM; it would certainly make backups easier.